# Azure database activity set

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In order to reduce costs on my Azure database, I'd like to turn it off automatically after 6 pm and turn it back on at 8 am on weekdays.
Is there some kind of "activity set" setting that we can apply on the Azure databases or Azure SQL Servers?

I am using the databases as a service solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to turn off your Azure SQL Database. A workaround would be to scale your databases using a script like the following https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-SQL-Database-e957354f. Depending on the size of your database you can drop the database to a basic which costs $5 a month.

Comment: You can downsize to lowest possible addition or just drop it and use PITR feature. The only catch with PITR is database not available instantly unlike downsizing it. Also any of the solution please consider SLAs before designing the solution.

Comment: @ckarst We're already at S0, so downgrading won't be possible. So they do charge per hour, but without possibility to turn it off?

Comment: You could downgrade to a basic if your DB is smaller than 2GB. To answer your question, correct an Azure SQL Database is charged per hour with no ability to pause.